# Visual Studio migration giving a "No suitable constructor" error for linestring in NetTopologySuite

Tags: gis, entity-framework-migrations

I am attempting to create a migration for my Node class which contains a Polygon from the NetTopologySuite. The error it gives is "No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'LineString'.

I've not used LineString anywhere, though it's probably part of the Polygon class. I can migrate without the polygon in my code, this is the only issue that's preventing it migrating.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor: Used for initialisation only
    /// </summary>
    public Node()
    {
        Name = "DEFAULT";
        Length = -1;
        Breadth = -1;
        DepthWithoutTide = -1;
        NodeArea = NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Polygon.Empty;

        NodeType = NodeType.Sea;
        BerthFunction = BerthFunction.NotApplicable;
        Water = Water.No;
        Waste = Waste.No;
        Refuel = Refuel.No;
        Immobilise = Immobilise.No;
    }
```

I have considered placing a LineString constructor, but I'm not sure how to do that effectively without it clashing with the NetTopologySuites constructors.